# Connecting a plot to a Button within Tkinter in Python

Tags: python, button, plot, lambda, tkinter

Here is my code:

```
def draw(x,y):
x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
y = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35]
print x
print y

angles = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 100)
size = 300000
plt.plot(size * np.cos(angles), size * np.sin(angles), "k")

plt.plot(x, y, 'ko', ms=3)
plt.show()



BtPlot = tk.Button(Sater, text=" Execute :\n \n \n SAVE & PLOT ",font=(None, 
20), fg= "black", bg="green", height=10,width = 15, 
command=lambda:draw(str(x.get()),str(y.get())))

BtPlot.grid(row=50, column=10, columnspan=1) 


Sater.mainloop()
```

I'm trying to plot from a button interface on Tkinter, but I'm getting this error each time: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'`. Could somebody please help me?

Comment: `get()` is for entry fields not list.

Comment: so i dont need to put get() ?

Comment: Thank you very much it's working

Comment: Your error is giving you the answer. `list` object (your x and y lists) have no attribute `get()` so you cannot use `get()` with list as list do not support that feature. to get data from a list you can use a for loop or index locations.

Comment: can you give me an exemple regarding my case of connecting strings out side the function with buttons

Comment: Can you be more specific with the kind of example you are looking for?

Comment: i'm loading txt files before def function so i got strings array .                    x1 = data[:,][3:,0]                                                                                    x1_col = x1.reshape(-1,1) once i'm trying to plot this in the def i'm getting error convert from string to float there is aways to do this for several columns without these errors thank's in advance

Answer (score 0):

**I am writing up the answer given by [Sierra Mountain Tech](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7475225/sierra-mountain-tech) in the above comments so that this question can be "closed". Full credits to [Sierra Mountain Tech](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7475225/sierra-mountain-tech).**

`get()` is for entry fields and not lists.

Your error is giving you the answer. `list` objects (your x and y lists) have no attribute `get()` and so you cannot use `get()` with lists as lists do not support that feature. To get data from a list you can use a `for loop` or `index locations`.

Answer (score 0):

In response to your comment:

> can you give me an exemple regarding my case of connecting strings out side the function with buttons?

I am not 100% sure about your question but I think you are asking for an example of how to concatenate or combine values from data you loaded in from a file.

so below I have given some examples of how to manipulate data inside of functions that was loaded in from outside of the function.

For non OOP examples you would normally need to use `global` in your functions to tell the function that the variable you are trying to work with is in the global namespace.

I have 4 data manipulation examples below. Take a look at each and let me know if you have any question.

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x175")

# lets say that we loaded x, y and z below from a json file.
x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
y = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35]
z = "123456789"

lbl1 = tk.Label(root, text = "Results: ")
lbl1.pack(side="bottom")

def combine_items():
    global x
    myvar = ""
    for item in x:
        myvar += str(item)
    lbl1.config(text ="Results:\n{}".format(myvar))

def add_each_item_of_y():
    global y
    myvar = 0
    for item in y:
        myvar += item
    lbl1.config(text ="Results:\n{}".format(myvar))

def add_x_and_y_per_index():
    global x, y
    myvar = []
    for i in range(len(x)):
        myvar.append(x[i] + y[i])
    lbl1.config(text ="Results:\n{}".format(myvar))

def convert_string_and_sum():
    global z
    myvar = 0
    for i in z:
        myvar += int(i)
    lbl1.config(text ="Results:\n{}".format(myvar))

btn1 = tk.Button(root, text = "Combine each item into one string",
                 command = combine_items).pack()
btn2 = tk.Button(root, text = "Get sum of all items in y",
                 command = add_each_item_of_y).pack()
btn3 = tk.Button(root, text = "Add each index of x and y together",
                 command = add_x_and_y_per_index).pack()
btn3 = tk.Button(root, text = "Conver each item of string into a number\nand then add them together",
                 command = convert_string_and_sum).pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: it's working perfectly, calling the strings and ploting every thing working well,about the pack i'm using the frame and the grid in my code there is some how replace the pack or mix it with them? To make all buttons on the same interface by changing the rows and the columns as we want without pack maybe?

Comment: @Sater I only used pack to make it a quick bit of code to throw together. You can replace pack with grid.

Comment: Thank you Sierra for your help, this my the last question promess i succed to load my txt file from a button but i'm trying to delimeter also which kind of function should i use§? "                                                        def 
     openInstruktion():
      from os import startfile
       startfile("c:")

         instruktionBtn = Button(Sater, text='load excel ', command = 
          openInstruktion)
             instruktionBtn.grid(row=6, column=9)

Comment: @Sater 1st Make sure you set all your imports at the top of your program. 2nd if you are loading an excel file you might want to use something like `openpyxl` to read and manage excel files as I do not believe tkinter supports excel files by default.